# images not uploaded on Cloudinary with Solidus and active_storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloudinary, solidus

i created a shop.

i host images on Cloudinary. I can load images on local and production but i don't find them on cloudinary.

i follow:
https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem
https://github.com/0sc/activestorage-cloudinary-service

gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.6'


gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.5'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'


gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false
gem 'solidus'
gem 'solidus_auth_devise'

gem 'cloudinary'
gem 'activestorage-cloudinary-service'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

config/storage.yml

```
cloudinary:
  service: Cloudinary
  cloud_name: <%= ENV['CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME'] %>
  api_key:    <%= ENV['CLOUDINARY_API_KEY'] %>
  api_secret: <%= ENV['CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET'] %>
```

config/environments/production.rb

```
config.active_storage.service = :cloudinary
```

spree.rb: lines about paperclip are commented

```
# Enable Paperclip adapter for attachments on images and taxons
  # config.image_attachment_module = 'Spree::Image::PaperclipAttachment'
  # config.taxon_attachment_module = 'Spree::Taxon::PaperclipAttachment'
```

storage.yml

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

cloudinary:
  service: Cloudinary
```

i tried to test it in local, the mage appear on the app but not on the hosting system.

config/environments/development.rb

```
 config.active_storage.service = :cloudinary
```

config/cloudinary.yml

```
development:
  cloud_name: xxx
  api_key: 'xxx'
  api_secret: xxx
  enhance_image_tag: true
  static_file_support: false
production:
  cloud_name: xxx
  api_key: 'xxx'
  api_secret: xxx
  enhance_image_tag: true
  static_file_support: true
test:
  cloud_name: xxx
  api_key: 'xxx'
  api_secret: xxx
  enhance_image_tag: true
  static_file_support: false
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

i find a solution

integrate cloudinary with active_record

gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1' 
# Use Active Storage variant
gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'
gem 'cloudinary'
gem 'activestorage-cloudinary-service'
```

then

```
bundle install
```

Active_record need rails >6.1

```
bundle update rails
```

cloudinary.yml or set environnement variable on your server

```
development:
  cloud_name: xxx
  api_key: 'xxx'
  api_secret: xxx
  enhance_image_tag: true
  static_file_support: false
production:
  cloud_name: xxx
  api_key: 'xxx'
  api_secret: xxx
  enhance_image_tag: true
  static_file_support: true
test:
  cloud_name: xxx
  api_key: 'xxx'
  api_secret: xxx
  enhance_image_tag: true
  static_file_support: false
```

spree.rb

```
# Enable Paperclip adapter for attachments on images and taxons
  config.image_attachment_module = 'Spree::Image::ActiveStorageAttachment'
  config.taxon_attachment_module = 'Spree::Taxon::ActiveStorageAttachment'
```

storage.yml

```
....
cloudinary:
  service: Cloudinary
```

config/environnements/production.rb

```
config.active_storage.service = :cloudinary
```

if it raises an error.

```
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'service_name' for ActiveStorage::Blob.):

rails active_storage:update

rails db:migrate
```

the DB need to be empty of products if else it raises an error

https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/discussions/3930#discussioncomment-361391

Answer (score 0):

Would you kindly submit a ticket indicating your cloud name so I can investigate for you?
Best,
Mo